# Unable to store command output in variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am executing below script but i get an error "`line 14: last-tag=TSTA-6: command not found`" i.e. at the point i try to store the command output in variable (TSTA-6 is output of command). Any ideas where am i going wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This script will remote trigger tagging job. Kindly provide Inputs"

release=-1

if [ -z "$1" ];then
 echo "Enter release number [In 3 digit format i.e. 20.0.0] "
 read release
else
 release="$1";
fi

 last-tag=$(svn ls -v https://abc.com/tags | sort -k1 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f7 | cut -d'/' -f1)  
echo "release is: $last-tag "
```

Comment: try lasttag instead of last-tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shell is looking for a command called `last-tag=TSTA-6` because "last-tag" is not a valid variable name, so once the shell sees the dash `-` in `last-tag`, the shell begins to look for a command.  As in the comments, change `last-tag` to a valid variable name such as `lasttag` or `last_tag`.

Comment: Thanx a lot. It resolved the issue.